# sad face on canvas in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While I was testing out a bug to do with window zoom and a `canvas` element on my website, I noticed that after a few resizes the `canvas` element had a small *sad face* imprinted on it (and one I did not create). Does anyone know what this means and why it might be there?

**Screenshot:** 
[image: the sad face]

Although funny, it's *very* confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to arise when setting `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to very high values. The following snippet replicates that problem (if you are on chrome).

```js
const canvases = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");

canvases[0].getContext("2d").fillRect(
  0,
  0,
  canvases[0].width,
  canvases[0].height,
);

canvases[1].getContext("2d").fillRect(
  0,
  0,
  canvases[1].width,
  canvases[1].height,
);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>canvas 1: regular<p>

<!--normal values-->
<canvas width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

<p>canvas 2: very high width and height<p>

<!--very high values-->
<canvas width="100000" height="100000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because Google Chrome failed to render the canvas at that point, the issue could also include your hardware configuration.

Try re-installing Google Chrome or close all the google chrome processes from your task manager and start again.

There is a thread discussing about this: [Google Support Thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4005897?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum canvas element size depends on the browser.
These are popular browser size limits:

https://jhildenbiddle.github.io/canvas-size/#/?id=test-results